# Putting shapefile on map in ArcGIS Online using ArcGIS Python API and Jupyter Notebook

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcgis-online, arcgis-python-api, jupyter-notebook, attributeerror

I inserted a shapefile (in .zip as required) to ArcGIS Online through Jupyter notebook:

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
my_gis = GIS()
m = my_gis.map()

#let's put the shape file to AGOL
shp_item = my_gis.content.add(item_properties={ 
        'title' : 'London RW 5',
        'type' : 'Shapefile',
        'tags' : 'MCAS'},
        data = r"C:\temp\rw0293.zip")

#let's get that shape file from AGOL
rw_line = my_gis.content.get("xxxx511dd7axxxxxbd026302b00bxxxx") 
rw_line

#let's put the shape file on map
m.add_layer(rw_line)
```

I see in ArcGIS Online that something with title "London RW 5" was added there with certain ID ("xxxx511dd7axxxxxbd026302b00bxxxx").

It seems to work, rw_line refers to this shapefile but how can I get it on a map?

I tried m.add_layer(rw_line) but this results in an error (below).

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
In  [38]:
Line 1:     m.add_layer(masw_layer)
File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\widgets\_mapview\_mapview.py, in add_layer:
Line 1402:  options["renderer"] = json.loads(item.renderer.json)
File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\features\layer.py, in renderer:
Line 143:   if self._renderer is None and "drawingInfo" in self.properties:
File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\__init__.py, in properties:
Line 14176: self._hydrate()
File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\__init__.py, in _hydrate:
Line 14228: self._refresh()
File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\__init__.py, in _refresh:
Line 14164: raise e
File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\__init__.py, in _refresh:
Line 14157: dictdata = self._con.post(self.url, params, token=self._lazy_token)
File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\_impl\_con\_connection.py, in post:
Line 955:   if url.find("://") == -1:
File C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\bin\Python\envs\arcgispro-py3\lib\site-packages\arcgis\gis\__init__.py, in __getattr__:
Line 10400: "'%s' object has no attribute '%s'" % (type(self).__name__, name)
AttributeError: 'Item' object has no attribute 'find'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/api-reference/arcgis.mapping.toc.html?highlight=add_layer#arcgis.mapping.WebMap.add_layer), the add_layer method accepts a **feature layer type** and your `rw_line` is **shapefile**.
You need to first `publish()` your **rw_line shapefile** object. Following would do the job

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
my_gis = GIS()
m = my_gis.map()

#let's put the shape file to AGOL
shp_item = my_gis.content.add(item_properties={ 
        'title' : 'London RW 5',
        'type' : 'Shapefile',
        'tags' : 'MCAS'},
        data = r"C:\temp\rw0293.zip")


#let's get that shape file from AGOL
rw_line = my_gis.content.get("xxxx511dd7axxxxxbd026302b00bxxxx") 
rw_line

#make feature layer
rw_layer = rw_line.publish() 

#let's put the shape file on map
m.add_layer(rw_layer)
```